# CSS hack for Mac OS Safari 13.1 and older version

Tags: html, css, safari

I am working on the project where it required that website should be cross browser compatible. In `safari 13.1` Catalina some css properties not working so for this browser only is there any css hack ? Please let me know if there is the solution to attain this.

I am using bootstrap 5.3 and its flex gap classes not working in safari 13.1 browser but working on newer browsers. So for this specific browser i need to set these gap classes with margin. Like this:

```
 .container {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      /* gap replacement, part 1 */
      margin: -5px;
    
      /* demo only properties omitted */
    }
    
    .item-b {
      flex: 1;
      /* gap replacement, part 2 */
      margin: 5px;
    
      /* demo only properties omitted */
    }
```

I only required this above code snippet for `safari 13.1` because Flex gap working on newer versions

Thanks

I have tried browser-hack but still cannot find any solution.

Comment: Please include some code so we have an example of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I have updated question with code and explained a bit more. May be you could help me @Sebi

Comment: This might help: https://www.giovannibenussi.com/blog/polyfill-flex-gap

Comment: Is the problem happens in mobile browser or in desktop browser?

Comment: @NizalSha desktop

Comment: Can you give the bootstrap classes for gap you are using?

Comment: Like this :
   <div class="d-flex gap-2">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Cancel This Appointment</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Keep Booking</button>
   </div>